# Adding model to a collection not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to play around with Backbone and seem to have run into a problem. My event is firing but the collection is not being updated. I've include the event callback below but the whole example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/xp27dm7L/7/

```
 addItem: function() {
    alert(1)
    var id = this.collection.length;
    this.collection.add({
        "id": "p"+id,
        "name" : "ghgjhj",
        "title" : "EsssyyyyEEE",
        "background" : "ssssFyFFF"
    });
},
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding an item with a duplicate ID.

If you do the following, it works:

```
this.collection.add({
    "id": "p"+Math.random(), // Just an example, of course!
    "name" : "ghgjhj",
    "title" : "EsssyyyyEEE",
    "background" : "ssssFyFFF"
 });
```

Ideally, you might not declare the `id` at all and let Backbone handle that:

```
this.collection.add({
    "name" : "ghgjhj",
    "title" : "EsssyyyyEEE",
    "background" : "ssssFyFFF"
});
```

You can also use the `length` of your collection to set the new id:

```
var id = this.collection.length + 1;
this.collection.add({
   "id": "p" + id, 
   "name" : "ghgjhj",
   "title" : "EsssyyyyEEE",
    "background" : "ssssFyFFF"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's ignoring the new item because it has a duplicate id.  This should fix it ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xshpLyh7/)):

```
var id = this.collection.length + 1;
```

[Here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) is the relevant note from the Backbone docs:

> If you're adding models to the collection that are already in the collection, they'll be ignored, unless you pass {merge: true}, in which case their attributes will be merged into the corresponding models ...

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the merge option.